# How to make the async.each wait for the .save() to be completed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to save some data into my collection, using mongoose.

```js
//tried with async each
async.each(indexes, function(index, callback) {
            newChampion.ID = champions[index].id;
            newChampion.Key = champions[index].key;
            newChampion.Name = champions[index].name;
            newChampion.Title = champions[index].title;
            Champion.addChampion(newChampion, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err.message);
                    callback();
                } else {
                    callback();
                }
});
```

The problem is that it pushes me only the value corresponding to the last index.(out of 133 values). I have the ID unique, so that is why there is only one value saved in the data base. I placed a console.log into the addChampion function and for 133 times I see the same value. Add champion snippet added below:

```js
module.exports.addChampion = function(newChampion, callback) {
    newChampion.save(callback);
}
```

How I solve this problem, in order to have all 133 values pushed into the DB?

Comment: I'd recommend not having only a single `newChampion` object but rather to create 133 of them in your loop…

Answer (score 0):

Async job with my local mysql:

```
let async = require('async');
let mysql = require('mysql');

var conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'xxxxx',
    database: 'xxxxx',
    port: 3306
});

var sqls = [
    'select id from record where id = 1',
    'select id from record where id = 2',
    'select id from record where id = 3',
    'select id from record where id = 4',
    'select id from record where id = 5'
];

async.each(sqls, function(sql, callback) {
    console.log(sql);
    conn.query(sql, function (err, res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
});
### output ###
select id from record where id = 1
select id from record where id = 2
select id from record where id = 3
select id from record where id = 4
select id from record where id = 5
[ RowDataPacket { id: 1 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { id: 2 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { id: 3 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { id: 4 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { id: 5 } ]
```

Simple case with not a really async job :

```
let async = require('async');

let addChampion = function(newChampion, callback) {
    console.log(newChampion)
}

indexes = [1, 2, 3];
async.each(indexes, function(index, callback) {
    newChampion = {};
    newChampion.ID = index;
    addChampion(newChampion, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
    })
});

### output ###
{ ID: 1 }
{ ID: 2 }
{ ID: 3 }
```

Would you check your `newChampion` before passing into the `addChampion` function? It's really wired you can the same index at console in it.

Comment: The answer could be improved by pointing out that the same `newChampion` object is being used for each entry in `indexes`. If  the `each` function is executed for all entries in `indexes` before `addChampion` gets to update the database, all updates will be for the last index entry processed.